# How to select only the first instance of an element with a class name when multiple are nested under it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to create an accordion type menu for a project and I have the need for there to be nested accordions under a parent accordion.

Right now, I have some markup like this:

```
<section class="accordions">
   <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion__title">
         <h3>Parent 1</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion__content">
         <p>Blah. Blah. Blah.</p>
         <div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion__title">
               <h3>Child 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion__content">
               <p>Blah. Blah. Blah.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion__title">
               <h3>Child 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion__content">
               <p>Blah. Blah. Blah.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion__title">
               <h3>Child 3</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion__content">
               <p>Blah. Blah. Blah.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion__title">
         <h3>Parent 2</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion__content">
         <p>Blah. Blah. Blah.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion__title">
         <h3>Parent 3</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion__content">
         <p>Blah. Blah. Blah.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

I use some simple JQuery to manage the clicks:

```
$('.accordions .accordion').find('.accordion__title').click(function(){
        
        var $toggle = $(this).parent();
        
        if($toggle.hasClass('accordion--open')) {
            $toggle.removeClass('accordion--open');
            $toggle.find('.accordion__content').slideUp(300);
            return false;
        }
        
        $toggle.find('.accordion__content').slideDown(300);
        $toggle.addClass('accordion--open');
        
    });
```

The issue I am running into is when a user clicks the parent accordion, then the child accordions are all open too. I believe the issue is with this line: `$toggle.find('.accordion__content').slideDown(300);`, as its causing all of the `accordion_content` elements to `slideDown` from the parent.

Any thoughts on some ways around this?

Comment: use `children` instead of `find` it gets the direct child - https://api.jquery.com/children/.  Or if you are binding the click to the title, why not just use `$(this).next()` to get the content div

Comment: or use [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) given `.accordion__content` sits beside title. `next` also works, assuming you will have the content placed immediately after title.